Flutter menu item "open IOS module in xcode" missing
in Android-Studio on macOS the menu item "open IOS module in xcode" is missing after restart
Somehow the menu item disappeared and I don't know how to get it back.


If you open an ios specific file like Info.plist does it not show that option in file tab?

oh man, you're right. Is this new after an update? Thank you

Not sure how new it is.. but i have been seeing it since 2 years now :)

select the ios folder or any ios file like Info.plist
thanks to Clevino Alrin
